# Issue when delete a logged in user in symfony3

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I have logged in as user and tried to delete the same account. But getting the below error instead of redirecting to login page the error pop up. This issue happens in symfony 3. I have used serialized and deserialized method in the user entiry

Error:
You cannot refresh a user from the EntityUserProvider that does not contain an identifier. The user object has to be serialized with its own identifier mapped by Doctrine.

Please suggest